# Julia println() not printing/inconsistent behavior

Tags: julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

This is probably a beginner question, but I could not find anything relevant in the docs or basic tutorials.  I am using Julia 1.4.2 (that is the latest stable release), and, as suggested in the docs/tutorials, the Atom editor with Juno.  This is on Ubuntu 18.04.

My minimum reproducible example:

```
function main()
    b = 300000
    println(b)
    println(b, " asdf")
end

main()
```

seems to sometimes output, as expected,

```
300000
300000 asdf
```

but it often outputs only

```
300000 asdf
```

The latter "wrong" output seems to occur most often when Julia is stopped, and I click "Run All", which starts Julia and runs the script. What is happening here? I apologize if this is a trivial beginner mistake.  Thank you.

Comment: I'd guess this is just the editor being buggy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Atom IDE.

Unfortunately Atom Juno from time to time is "eating" the first output line of a Julia script - I have seen it few times.

The workaround that seems to work is to force a flush on the standard output cache:

```
flush(stdout)
```

This cleans the cache and enforces the communication between Julia REPL and Atom.